# Como puedo compilar mis archivos php con gulp?

Tags: php, html, css, gulp

Estoy trabajando con sass, la cual no he tenido problemas para compilar y tener todo el css en un archivo llamado main.css, y el scss si tenerlos por separado para cada componente.

Tengo esta estructura

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tambien estoy usando php para usar el contenido que se repite en todas las paginas, como header y footer con los "include" por ejemplo en index.php, tengo los includes para el header y el footer.

asi tengo mi index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>Nature Online</title>
    <?php include "./src/layout/meta.html" ?>
</head>

<body>
    <header class="text-bg-light sticky-top">
        <?php include "./src/layout/header.html" ?>
    </header>

    <main class="container">
        <?php include "./src/pages/home.php" ?>
    </main>
    
    <footer class="container-footer">
        <?php include "./src/layout/footer.html" ?>
    </footer>

    <?php include "./src/layout/scripts.html" ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Mi pregunta es la siguiente, es posible usar gulp para procesar los php de tal forma, que en dist me llegue el index.php con el html en lugar de include "archivo.html";

Tengo este código, pero lo que hace es mandarme el index.php a dist tal cual, como si lo copiara y pegara nada más.

Y segun esta linea .pipe(replace(/include\s*[(]"(.+?)"[)]/g, function(match, filename), se supone que leeria los archivos del include y trae su contenido, pero no.

```
gulp.task('process-php', function() {
    return gulp.src(['index.php', 'src/**/*.php'])
        .pipe(replace(/include\s*[(]"(.+?)"[)]/g, function(match, filename) {
            console.log('Reemplazando include:', filename);           
            return '<?php include("' + filename + '"); ?>';
        }))
        .pipe(phpMinify()) // Minificar el código PHP
        .pipe(rename({ extname: '.php' })) // Cambiar la extensión del archivo a .php
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist')); // Carpeta de destino
});
```

Agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: No me queda claro, quieres que en vez de hacer el include, traiga todo el código del archivo ?

Comment: Si, osea cuando se pase a la carpeta dist, ahi contenga todo el html sin includes

Comment: Mi plan seria, que al subirlo a un servidor solo sea subir, por ejemplo, el solo index.php sin subir también los layouts, pero pues no sé si sea posible

Comment: leer no es lo mismo que remplazar... aunque dudo que funcione